# Incorrect pattern displayed

Tags: python

In the second while loop the asterisk(*) is displayed just once for every cycle.

```
import sys

n = 0
a = 0

while (n < 6):
    n = n + 1
    while(a < n):
        sys.stdout.write('*')
        a = a +1
    print ''
```

Pattern displayed is :

```
*
*
*
*
*
*
```

Comment: what is your problem ?

Comment: What pattern were you expecting? The most likely problem is that you never reset `a` back to zero at the start of the loop.

Comment: This would be much easier with two nested for loops.

Comment: `print('*' * n)` saves you a loop, a variable and a print statement.

Comment: You don't reset the value of `a`, so it is always just one less than `n`.

Comment: Thank you, After resetting the value of a to 0, it workded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want it to print out 6 patterns of 6 stars with a line between, this is what you want to do:

```
import sys

n = 0
a = 0

while (n < 6):
    n = n + 1
    a=0
    while(a < n):
        sys.stdout.write('*',end="")
        a = a +1
    print ''
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution for your version:

```
import sys

n = 0
a = 0

while (n < 6):
    n = n + 1
    a = 0
    while(a < n):
        print('*', end="")
        a = a + 1
    print('')
```

If you want a shorter version, here's a possible one:

```
print('\n'.join(['*'*i for i in range(1,7)]))
```